# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $\{a_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a decreasing  sequence of real numbers, $a_{n}\in (0,1)$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n}=0$. What we can say about $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}$$

Comment: If it exists, it is greater than $1$.  Don't think you can say much more than that.

Comment: (That should be "greater than or equal to $1$, of course, as I showed below.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably not much.

Let $a_n = b^{-n}$ for any constant $b > 1$, so then $a_n \in (0, 1)$.  Then,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b^{-n + 1}}{b^{-n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} b = b.$$

So, any real number greater than 1 is possible.  And, if $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then a limit of 1 is also possible.  And, using $a_n = b^{-n^2}$, we see $\infty$ is also a possible limit.  The limit would have to be at least 1, in general, if $a_n$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 3):

Let $b_1,...,b_n,...$ be any sequence of positive real numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i$ diverges.

Then let $a_0 = 1$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{1+b_n}$.

Then $a_{n-1}/a_{n}= 1+b_{n-1}$.

Now, since $\sum b_i$ diverges, $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1+b_i)$ diverges.

But $a_{n} = \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n (1+b_i)}$

So $a_{n}\to 0$.

On the other hand, $\lim a_{n-1}/a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1+b_n)$

Clearly, that can converge, diverge, bop around.  It can even converge to $1$, by setting $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: On the second-to-last line, wouldn't it be $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+b_n}$?

Comment: Ah, I got the earlier line backwards. I fixed it.  It should have been $a_{n-1}/a_n = 1+b_{n-1}$, and I had the numerator and denominator switched

Answer (score 2):

We show that the behaviour of the $\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$ can be extremely chaotic.

In particular, we show that there is a decreasing sequence of positive reals, with limit $0$, such that **every** real number in the interval $[1,\infty)$ is a limit of a subsequence of the $\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$.

Let $r_0,r_1,r_2,\dots$ be an enumeration of the positive rationals, and let $s_n=\sum_{i=0}^n r_i$. Then $(s_n)$ is an increasing positive sequence, with limit $\infty$.

Let $a_n=e^{-s_n}$.  Then $\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}=e^{r_n}$.

For any real number $x\ge 1$, there is a subsequence of $(r_n)$ which has limit $\log(x)$, and the result follows.